# Filtering a df by date in a loop within a function

Tags: r

I've been having some trouble with what I would think is a pretty simple issue. I have a function which takes as an input a list of dataframes and a date range, filters the dataframes by date, and then does some other stuff. Simply put, it looks like this:

```
my_function <- function(df_list, date_range = c(min, max)) {
  for(i in 1:length(df_list)) {
    df_list[[i]] <- df_list[[i]][df_list[[i]]$date >= as.Date(date_range[1])]
    df_list[[i]] <- df_list[[i]][df_list[[i]]$date <= as.Date(date_range[2])]
  }
  etc
}
```

With the above, I get an error `undefined columns selected`. I've also tried with filters and lapply, as in:

```
lapply(df_list, function(df) {
  df <- filter(df, week >= as.Date(date_range[1]))
  df <- filter(df, week <= as.Date(date_range[2]))
}
```

Which doesn't give an error but still doesn't work.

I feel like this isn't as hard as I'm making it. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is that `[df_list[[i]]$date <= as.Date(date_range[2])]` needs a comma before the closing `]`, since you're subsetting a data.frame. I've been confounded by that error message plenty of times.

Comment: Check this link to get deeper on subsetting: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use `lapply` for this. You could achieve what you want using:

```
date_range <- as.Date(date_range) # no need to do this on every iteration of the lapply function
df_list <- lapply(df_list,
  function(x) x[x$week >= date_range[1] & x$week <= date_range[2], ])
```

As @Frank has pointed out, the main issue with your first piece of code is that you're missing a trailing comma when subsetting. For the second, it should work but you need to assign it back to `df_list`.